# How can I automatically choose and process every image in /root/facedetect directory instead of choosing a specific image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

If that can be done, is there any way to automatically send in a separate directory all images with detected faces, or zip them?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/root/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

img = cv2.imread('/root/facedetect/1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this script from anywhere (`os` module is useful in that case):

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

path = `root/facedetect`  # Set your path, where are images exists
files = os.listdir(path)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in '%s': %s" % (path, files))
# Remain only files with specified type
files = [f for f in files if ".jpg" in f or ".jpeg" in f]
# Create directory if not exists:
newpath = path + "/recognized"
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
# Specify classifier:
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/root/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
# Loop over each and save in a new directory
for i in files:
    # Path to image
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, i))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    # Proceed if detect at least one face
    if faces != ():
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(newpath, i), img)
print("Done")
```

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. Except one thing: that exports all jpg images to recognized directory, images with face detected and also images with no face at all. Is there any way I can only export images with detected faces but not the others?

Comment: @jon, please, look at updated answer. I added jpeg and save only if face detected

Comment: Thank you @Oysiyl ! Now it works like a charm! 
One more question please: what does "f" symbolise in "files = [f for f in files if ".jpg" in f or ".jpeg" in f]"? Can I use another letter instead of "f" for example or should it be "f"?

Comment: @jon, of course! I suggest you spend a few minutes on the reading what is `list comprehension` is. You can use any letter you wish (except `files` - because of script iterate through this list). And, if you need to select additional files such as ".png" -  just add  `or ".png" in f`. Note: if you have in your directory many files with different suffix(".png",".svg" and few others) - you can specify `files` as `files = [f for f in files if "." in f]` (select all things in directory, if that thing have "." in name)

Comment: thank a lot indeed @Oysiyl ! Please one last thing, this is urgent! If python file is lets say in /root/pictures and from terminal I run "python /root/pictures/file.py" it will process files in /root directory and not in /root/pictures directory. I need it to process pictures in /root/pictures because I need to run it like "python /root/pictures/file.py" and I cant run it like "cd pictures" then "python file.py". I would highly appreciate an answer since its urgent for today. If it can be please if you could update it.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jon, I update my answer (place your `.py` script where you want). Try to run code -  it should work! If you have any errors, describe and I try to answer (if be online, of course).

Comment: Yeah @Oysiyl  ,I managed to resolve that by doing the same. Thanks a lot. But there is a thing. My professor asked me today two questions that confused me. 1: Why is it “f for f in files” and not “for f in files” like the usual usage of ‘for’? And nr. 2 was: Why is that [f for f in files......]” in square brackets? What are the square brackets, what do they mean? Why wouldn’t it be used with no brackets?

Comment: @jon, I strongly recommend you read from [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) about `list comprehension` (simple for loop in another manner). It is an answer to your first question. For seconds: `[]` means a python data structure, which called `list`. When you have some values, you usually fill a list with them (without that you can not operate on them). And then make some actions: such as remove that elements, which have not `.` in their name. It's an answer for the second question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module to get all images in the folder.
And then use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module to copy some images in another folder.

```py
    import osimage_path
    from shutil import copyfile

    images_folder = '/root/facedetect'
    images = os.listdir(images_folder)

    detected_faces_folder = '/root/detected_faces'

    for image in images:
        image_path = os.path.join(images_folder, image)
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ...
        ...

        if detected_faces:
            copyfile(image_path, os.path.join(detected_faces_folder, image))
```